# Cython throws SyntaxError on cdef-class

Tags: compilation, syntax-error, cython

I want to create a simple class with the cdef statement, but it shows me a SyntaxError.

```
cdef class MyClass:
    pass
```

[image: The error occuring when compiling with Cython to a .c file.]

*This is my self-written cy-compile script. Yes, I'm sure the script is not causing the problem.*

### **What the heck is wrong here ?!**

Thanks :)

**EDIT**:
My file was name `.py` and not `.pyx` and this caused the error. *shame on me*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suffix was `.py` and not `.pyx` and this caused the error.

Comment: Hm, added this answer to mark the questions as answered but I can only mark the answer as accepted in 2 days . xD